# Spring-boot - how to use both Resteasy JAX-RS and Spring MVC controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a jax-rs resources which I am trying to convert to spring boot. I have made them work but looks like some of jax-rs resources which are included in project as dependencies from other projects. I know it should be a service! Anyway so I may be able to make change to that library and make them mvc compatible but is there another way I can make spring servlet work with both? I am using all java based configuration btw no xml.

Main application class is currently annotated as following unless I add "/*" in url-mapping which moots the point of adding this. I don't even see why I should add this if dispatcher servlet can find handler for every /* request.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { EmbeddedServletContainerFactory.class })
@EnableAsync
@ImportResource(value = { "classpath:springmvc-resteasy.xml" })
public class Application implements AsyncConfigurer, DisposableBean { .. }
```

I think with above spring DispatcherServlet is still at front in control and it knows of rest easy handleradapters. By default boot also maps everything under '/' so I dont understand why it doesnt work. I am getting 404 when hitting jax-rs uri, spring mvc uri works.

I tried to add following but after that everything stopped working.

```
@Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean initServlet(DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet) {

        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean 
        = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet, false,"/jaxrs-api/*", "/mvc-api/*");

        servletRegistrationBean
    .setName(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME);

        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }
```

I can see following beans are being loaded for resteasy upon context initialization.

```
resteasy.deployment
resteasy.registry
resteasy.dispatcher
resteasy.providerFactory
resteasy.spring.bean.processor
abstract.resteasy.handlerMapping
resteasy.handlerMapping
resteasy.handlerAdapter
resteasy.exception.handler
resteasy.no.resource.found.view
reateasy.error.view.resolver
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like things started working again after some try and errors which is not the way this should be! Spring-boot really should document here how it can work with spring mvc and jax-rs in co-existence.

Here's the sequence of changes I did.

I added @EnableWebMvc to my Application.java class or It can be on any other @Configuration class

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { EmbeddedServletContainerFactory.class })
@EnableAsync
@EnableWebMvc
@ImportResource(value = { "classpath:springmvc-resteasy.xml" })
public class Application implements AsyncConfigurer, DisposableBean { .. }
```

In hindsight I knew this gonna create some problem and it did! My additional MessageConverter stopped working. I had following in Application.java

```
@Bean
  public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter customJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper scalaObjectMapper = new ScalaObjectMapper();
    //scalaObjectMapper.enable(features)
    //objectMapper.registerModule(new DefaultScalaModule());
    scalaObjectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(scalaObjectMapper);
    return jsonConverter;
  }
```

Now I had to move it to another config class which overrides WebMvcConfigurerAdapter to customize spring mvc beans.

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class WebMvcCustomConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  /**
   * Registering Scala ObjectMapper
   * @return
   */
  @Bean
  public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter customJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper scalaObjectMapper = new ScalaObjectMapper();
 scalaObjectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(scalaObjectMapper);
    return jsonConverter;
  }

  @Override
  public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

    //converters.add(ScalaObjectMapper);
    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    converters.add(customJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
  }
}
```

So looks like now Spring MVC has some control rather then Spring Boot. I am sure this is gonna break loose when I have some additional components for example swagger2 integration or something similar.

Comment: Hi @nir , did integration went smooth. because i am also trying  to co-exist  both so that in future I cn use just REST